# Split text file into multiple by regex

Tags: bash

For the last 3 years we've been running a daily task scheduler to collect spam emails and combine them into a file which can be used for SpamAssassin training.
Combining them was not necessary for SpamAssassin but it was done to make them more manageable as over time there are over 2 million individual spam emails.

Due to the size of this is getting, around 10GB, we've come up with a new way to do spam training and organizing the messages individually in grouped compressed archives.

The Question
We would like to split all of these combined emails back into seperate files.

It should be fairly straight forward. We need to identify where the last email ended and the new email starts and then split that off into a new file.

I would like to know what's available to accomplish this, preferability something that will work on BASH for Mac or Ubuntu.

[Image of combined emails text file where one message ends and the next starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D11ip.png)

I have tried using bash csplit command to split the messages by the beginning line "From: ...... ....."

```
csplit -k -f xx -n 18 "spam--2009-05-17" '/From\ .*@.*[Mon|Tue|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun].*/' {9999999999999}
```

Running this command has the intended effect but I worry that it might split the header in the case that the From: is not the first line in the emails header, and I'm concerned that it may also match with the contents within the email.

Comment: What is the result you get when you run the current command you've shown?

Comment: The command I provided works fine. It splits the single email file into roughly the right number of individual files.
My concern with the command I provided is that its may not be as accurate as I'd like, possibly matching on the contents of the email body rather than the header.
I should have been more clear in my question, I'd like input from other people on how I can be more accurate in splitting these emails out into individual files..